Different results between CLI and pre-commit
I've set up a pre-commit hook using Ruff to handle linting in my project. I've configured the hook as per the documentation:
- repo: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-pre-commit
  rev: v0.4.9
  hooks:
    - id: ruff
      args: [ --fix ]
    - id: ruff-format

To test this setup, I've created a script a.py with the following content:

"""Module contains functions related to greetings."""

def get_greeting(name: str) -> str:
    """Return a greeting message.

    Args
        name (str): Name of the person to greet.

    Returns
        str: A greeting message.

    """
    return f"Hello, {name}!"

def hello() -> str:
    return "hello"

Running ruff check a.py from the command line gives me 3 errors:
a.py:8:5: D416 [*] Section name should end with a colon ("Args")
a.py:12:5: D416 [*] Section name should end with a colon ("Returns")
a.py:20:5: D103 Missing docstring in public function
Found 3 errors.
[*] 2 fixable with the `--fix` option.

However, when I run pre-commit run, it passes without any errors. Am I missing something in my configuration?


name of the file does not match the output. 2. is the file being committed  ? if you run ruff check on cli, it will run against all files but precommit hook should run the check only against the changed / new files in in the current commit.


@rasjani 1. Sorry that was a typo, I already changed. 2. Yes, both a.py and .pre-commit-config.yaml are commited. When I run the ruff check i select only the a.py file by using this ruff check a.py

If a.py is already committed, the pre-commit hook won't check it again until you modify it once more and make a new commit that affects it.

make sure you have the same versions in both places and you probably want pre-commit run --all-files to be apples-to-apples.  there's really nothing special about pre-commit that would make this different so I'm voting to close as "not reproducible"

also please show your full configuration and full output including the command you ran -- otherwise it's not possible to see what you're seeing

Loosely relevant, I was encountering a similar issue, except that:

pre-commit.ci would show a failure,
locally, both ruff check and pre-commit run --all-files would show a success.

It turned out that my ~/.ruff.toml had some ignored rules under [lint], which I had forgotten about.
